# What is the purpose of a rowguid column which is not used as id?

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I have to import data from an existing database. It has about 100 tables, and almost every one has a "rowguid" column, of type "uniqueidentifier". They also have "classic" integer identifiers used as primary and foreign keys, with auto increments.

So, I wonder : what can be the purpose of this "rowguid", if it is apparently not used anywhere ? Can it be useful for something on its own ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443036/ms-sql-server-row-guid-column

Comment: yes, this thread does answer my question, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

usually mssql uses such fields for replication needs

Comment: Having just torn down replication on a DB that's had it enabled for ~5 years, I'd just add that the DB may have been designed with replication in mind, even if it does not/no longer uses it. (Indeed, we've left the extra columns in place on ours, until we next work on schema changes)