# Using foreign key as RowGuidCol

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have the following scenario:
* I have an existing database with Tables A and B. 
* Table A has a primary key "ID", with is of the type uniqueidentifier, not nullable and marked as RowGuidCol.
* Table B has a foreign key "TableA_ID" which refers to the primary key "ID" in Table A.

Question:
Is there any reason, why I should not set the foreign key "ID" in Table B as RowGuidCol?
Per definition, "The ROWGUIDCOL property indicates that the uniqueidentifier values in the column uniquely identify rows in the table." [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx] So it would not matter, that the value is not unique across several tables, right?

Thanks for any thoughts on the subject!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a good reason. A RowGUID means that the value in each row is unique for that table. You have a foreign key here. If there is a 1:1 relationship between the tables, then you can set this attribute since each row will be associated with one and only one row in tableA. And that also means you can use this column as both primary and foreign keys. But if the relationship between the tables is 1:m, then you cannot do this because any number of rows in this table can have the same value for TableA_ID (when they are associated with the same row in tableA). And since this is mostly used for replication, refer to [MS SQL Server Row GUID Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443036/ms-sql-server-row-guid-column)

Comment: Thank you very much! I do have a 1:1 relationship, so will go ahead set the attribute.